# SharePoint 2010: Changing List View via a button or webpart

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

So this is my scenario. I have users of my site that are not operating at a high enough level to use the sort feature on a list's columns, or change the view of a list using the toolbar.

To make things easier, I'd like to create several views for a list and have a few buttons (or use an existing webpart) at the top of my list that could be clicked and which would re-sort the list data on the fly for them.

For instance, one button could be top ten based on reviews, this would pull the average rating column and sort in descending order.

Any ideas?

Comment: I found this: http://www.manula.com/manuals/lightning-tools/lightning-conductor-web-part-2013/2/en/topic/dynamically-selecting-a-view

Answer (score 1):

'On the fly' meaning without a page reload? If so, start looking into Javascript/Jquery solutions. [SPServices](http://spservices.codeplex.com/) would be a good starting point.

For a lo-fi solution, here goes.

Create all the views as you want them. Edit each view page and add CEWP's where you want the block of buttons to sit. Create images for your buttons. Add HTML to each CEWP such that your images display and are hyperlinked to the appropriate view. Voila. It's going to be a pain to manage if you want to make any changes. Maybe store that HTML block in Site Assets or something and reference it with a Page Viewer web-part. I think that would work...

Alternatively just link off the quick-launch. Yay.

Comment: Thanks Liam. Very helpful. Let me give this a try!

Comment: Will try this.. by quicklaunch you mean the left nav bar right?